# Web administer panel as standalone assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razorgenerator

Now I'm working on web analytic system, which is MVC based. While developing I got a good thought to extract web administer panel to separate assembly. It's for using in other my projects. So, in future I could just reference that assembly and don't care about layout web panel.

Web panel itself is just a markup of elements with some tight design. It contains main menu, submenu and a place for stuffing of needed other elements.

at the moment, I've got an assembly with all views in such panel using RazorGenerator.

The issue is how can I manage css files for such assembly? Should I just inline them to views and place that views to compiled assembly or deploy them as separate css files with assembly?

That css bundles would be compressed/minimized or any way combined in final project.

Answer (score 2):

You could package the css and js files as resources and have them served using the resource handler, but you wouldn't be able to edit them in future projects if a design exception comes up (e.g. you need to modify the a css class because it clashes with the main css of another project).

Why not create a nuget package? some advantages

- You have everything on a zip file (you don't have to publish the package to use it)
- You can add the project directly from the console
- The nuget creates the corresponding folder structure for views and controllers for the admin area
- If you need to remove it you just uninstall it and it takes away all the files.
- Plus, you have the flexibility to modify css and js files for the admin.
- This is easier than having a "black box" dll on your application that handles routes and serves packaged files hidden from the rest of the application.

Here are some tutorials on how to create your own nuget package:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/593605/All-you-need-to-create-a-Nuget-package-for-ASP-NET
- http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/using-a-gui-to-build-packages
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvcnuget_topic2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Is it a deployable assembly? For example, will it be added to lots of different systems, in different locations, or will it be used on say a corporate network?

If you're deploying the assembly then you probably want to compile the css as resources & use the ASP.Net built in resource handler to serve the css. You therefore have no dependencies on anything else, you pre-compress/minify the css & the host server can take care of caching.

If it's for a corporate network, or a servers you control, then put the css on a central server & have them all reference that location. The previous approach work just as well here though.

Comment: It's my way to use this panel in different projects, so all of future projects will have menu and submenu in their interfaces, so I'm looking for a way to reduce duplicating of code, putting repeating part to one assembly, which I could use in many projects by referencing it.